# Updating TextBox Value inside select event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to complete a textbox value with email providers such as gmail, yahoo etc. When a user enters the `@` character I am getting matched results from a webmethod. After that, I am trying to combine the old value of the textbox and the result. Then I set the value of the textbox to a combination of these values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  SearchText();
});

function SearchText() {
  $('#txtEmpName').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/GetEmployeeName",
        data: "{'empName':'" + request.term + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          response(data.d)
        }
      });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var oldValue = $('#txtEmpName').val();
      var value = oldValue + ui.item.value;
      //store in session
      console.log("set value ", $('#txtEmpName').val(value));
      $('#txtEmpName').val(value);
      document.valueSelectedForAutocomplete = value;
      document
    },
    minLength: 0
  });

  $('#txtEmpName').autocomplete("disable");

  $('#txtEmpName').keyup(function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    switch (code) {
      case 40: //down key
      case 38: //up key
        //add more cases for special buttons
        return;
    }

    var value = $('#txtEmpName').val();
    var last = value.slice(value.lastIndexOf('@'));
    var searchTerm = last[0];
    if (searchTerm == "@") {
      var valToSearch = value.slice(value.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
      $('#txtEmpName').autocomplete("enable");
      $('#txtEmpName').autocomplete("search", valToSearch);
    } else {
      $('#txtEmpName').autocomplete("disable");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific issue? All you've told us is what you're trying to do. Also, which autocomplete library are you using?

Comment: Also, just give `data` an object instead of hacking JSON together manually: `data: { empName: request.term },`